# Drawing a red line

Tags: c++, qt

I have a column of numbers displayed on a label. The numbers are all '1' to '6', in a different order on each line. Eg:

```
123456
214365
241635
214365......
```

I need to draw a red line through all the '1's. I realise that I'll need an overlaid widget to do this. I've looked at tutorials, and I've declared a paint event in the header file, and a

```
void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
```

in the .cpp file. I can draw a red line if I put hard numbers in as x and y co-ordinates - but I need it to be a function so I can pass it x and y variables.
 My question is: this paint event does not appear to be a function, so how can I call it with different start and end points (ie from one number '1' to the next, on the line below)? I am a total beginner, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you store x, y values in member variables? Then you can access those members (this.x, this.y) in `::paintEvent()` function.

Comment: Actually do don't need an overlay image. Inherit from your label, reimplement the paintEvent() and call Label::paintEvent(event) BEFORE your code.

Comment: Of course I meant overlay WIDGET. Just add an x,y-setter in your class (which you derived from the label class). You can not directly call the paintEvent method. just call update() or repaint() if you need to force a repaint (e.g. if painting relevant data has changed)

Comment: Thank you both. Ok - I'm calling the start and end points p1 and p2, and I've drawn the first section of the line in the paintEvent, but the thing I need to know, is how can I send the next two points and call something that draws the next section of line? How do I 'inherit' from my label? How do I 'reimplement' the paintevent? Like I said, I'm a total novice with this, and these terms mean nothing to me. I've searched online but I can't find anything that helps.

Comment: Sorry - I meant that the start and end points are p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y. I hust need to know how to make a function so that I can call it: something like

Comment: void drawnext( p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y)

Comment: Please help - I'm getting nowhere at all!